# Border controls between Finland and Norway in times of Covid-19

Tags: covid-19, norway

How does Norway enforce [its Covid-19 rules](https://www.fhi.no/en/op/novel-coronavirus-facts-advice/facts-and-general-advice/travel-advice-COVID19/) for foreign citizens at the border between Finland and Norway? Are there regular border controls at Karigasniemi, for instance?

Comment: Not having controls, doesn't mean you can break the rules. Both are in Schengen Area, so there should be no systematic control (but with CoViD, there are exception to Schengen rules)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Since Norway is not a member of the EU, border controls at the land border with Sweden and Finland are relatively common independent of the current covid situation (and legally not a problem) despite that all countries are in the Schengen area.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: which kind of control? Like here in CH, where you are just asked about items to declare (so mainly just tariff enforcement), but usually nothing about identity (and so no passport control), or the passport control is frequent?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Usually only customs control. Immigration control at the borders between Norway, Sweden and Finland is btw regulated by the Nordic Passport Union, which predates the Schengen agreement and prescribes an immigration control, which is much less strict than what is allowed by the Schengen regulations.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Owing to the Nordic Passport Union, the legality of Norway (and Denmark+Finland) refusing Nordic citizens entry is in fact a grey area. Went to Copenhagen in April, Oslo in May and Halden in June, and all times managed to talk my way in by referring to the Passport Union (it was a hassle, especially with the Danes, but still ended up fine)

Comment: @Crazydre That might be, but I don't think Norway has at any point during the covid situation refused entry to citizens of the other Nordic countries? There are and have been requirements to quarantine, but as far as I can remember no entry refusals.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You think wrong https://www.nettavisen.no/nyheter/innenriks/svensker-topper-listen-over-utlendinger-som-er-sendt-ut-av-norsk-politi-i-ar/3423965029.html

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  live in CH and there's frequently pure passport/visa control for Flixbuses entering. DE does it a lot too at the border from CH, and to a lesser degree FR and IT

Comment: @Crazydre You are right. The first regulation concerning covid related measurements was in effect until June 19th and did restrict most EEA citizens entry to Norway. The current regulation is more relaxed, but entry requirements are now mostly based on residency and not ciitzenship. Residents of EU/EEA countries and Switzerland are allowed to enter, while residents of other countries, also EU/EEA and Swiss citizens, are usually not allowed to enter. Be aware that there is a provision in the Nordic Passport Union allowing members to suspend the agreement.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo "Be aware that there is a provision in the Nordic Passport Union allowing members to suspend the agreement" Only with the approval of the Nordic *Gränshinderrådet* (dunno its English name). Made a discrete enquiry and apparently Norway, Finland and especially Denmark pushed hard for approval to shut the border to Nordic citizens, but this was out of the question, yet they then took the liberty of imposing bans anyway, with no one within the police of each country bothering to question the legality (which was evident when I addressed it at DK/NO borders)

Comment: @Crazydre Gränshinderrådet was not founded until 2014 and there is no provision in the agreement for any approval from them to suspend the agreement, just a requirement that the other nations are to be informed (article 15). Gränshinderrådet has critized the border closures, but not asked for anything more than that the closures shall be announced well in advance: https://www.norden.org/sv/news/granshinderradet-i-brev-till-statsministrarna-ta-fram-en-nordisk-krisstrategi

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Gränshinderrådet was indeed founded in 2014, but I was nonetheless told on the phone by a legal representative of the Nordic Council that the suspension of the Passport Union requires their approval (whilst the Nordic Council of Ministers - not the same - was responsible for that previously). But even in case that's a fact, the countries have done whatever they wanted, AND implementation has been chaotic, with Denmark often changing specifics from one day to the next, conflicting information coming from the authorities AND EVEN practices differing between ports of entry

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Anyway, the Nordic Council representative I spoke to couldn't or wouldn't point to any specific paragraph mandating that suspension of the Passport Union be approved, but said that's the "legal practice". That's why I didn't write the bans on Nordic citizens were outright illegal, but rather a grey area, as the Passport Union hasn't been nearly as relevant for border purposes since Schengen. Even so, I've ended up being able to enter DK/NO after arguing with officers initially insisting I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the enforcement is based on trust.

The border controls are certainly more frequent now than usual, but there are no regular or permanent controls when entering Norway from Finland or Sweden.

Comment: The controls are permanent in Svinesund (both the motorway and the old road). Also flights land at the non-Schengen terminal (all international flights)

Comment: @Crazydre I have relatives living just half an hour from Svinesund telling otherwise.

Comment: Must've been relaxed since mid-June then, when I took the Västtrafik local bus 111 from Strömstad to Svinesundsparken just to change coins worth 250 kroner to banknotes at Reka 1000 (exploiting the front doors of Swedish local/regional buses being closed thanks to COVID-19). It takes the old road, and I was the only one on the bus. Despite me clearly telling the police I'd be gone again within half an hour, they were REALLY reluctant to let me in (took about 5 minutes for them to budge), in fact even worse than on the motorway in May (when I took Bus4You to Oslo)

Comment: @Crazydre So you have crossed the border twice and therefore conclude that the controls are permanent? Independent of the covid situation, buses to Norway are often picked out for a control anyway and the controls at the motorway checkpoint at Svinesund are relatively frequent. I would guesstimate that the border is open (you can simply drive through on the motorway) about 1/3 of the time. 2/3 of the time, all traffic is lead off the motorway and through the customs checkpoint, but also there, most cars are simply waved through.

Comment: Nah, spoke to multiple daily commuters from Strömstad about it in May, who said it's a hard shut border, and one of them once forgot to bring their employment contract and was summarily sent back. Again, though, may well have been relaxed since as more exceptions were put into the directive.